# Using File.AppendAllText causes a "Process cannot access the file, already in use" error

Tags: c#, file-io, sharpdevelop

I am writing a simple keylogger program (for non-malicious purposes).

**Note:** This is with .net 4.0 Client Profile

Whenever I start the program, I get this error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\.. ..\bin\Debug\log.log' because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is my main code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Logger
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public string cWin = null;
        public static string nl = Environment.NewLine;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DialogResult AskOverwrite()
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Log already exists. Overwrite?", 
                "Overwrite?", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            return result;
        }

        private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
             {
                  systray.Visible = true;
                  this.Hide();    
             }
             else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
             {
                  systray.Visible = false;
             }
        }

        private void SystrayMouse_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Program.run)
            {
                output.AppendText(string.Format(e.KeyChar.ToString()));
                File.AppendAllText(Program.file, e.KeyChar.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Program.run)
            {
                if (File.Exists(Program.file))
                {
                    if (AskOverwrite() == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        File.Create(Program.file);
                    }
                }

                Program.run = true;
                output.AppendText(string.Format("Logging started - {1}{0}", nl, System.DateTime.Now));
                File.AppendAllText(Program.file, string.Format("Logging started - {1}{0}", nl, System.DateTime.Now));
            }
            else
            {
                output.AppendText(string.Format("Logging already started!{0}", nl));
            }
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Program.run)
            {
                Program.run = false;
                output.AppendText(string.Format("{0}Logging stopped - {1}{0}", nl, System.DateTime.Now));
                File.AppendAllText(Program.file, string.Format("{0}Logging stopped - {1}{0}", nl, System.DateTime.Now));
            }
            else
            {
                output.AppendText(string.Format("Logging already stopped!{0}", nl));
            }
        }

        private void getWindowTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cWin != CurrentWindow.GetActiveWindow() &&Program.run)
            {
                cWin = CurrentWindow.GetActiveWindow();
                if (cWin != null)
                {
                    output.AppendText(string.Format("{0}Window - {1}{0}", nl, cWin));
                    File.AppendAllText(Program.file, string.Format("{0}Window - {1}{0}", nl, cWin));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? It was fine when I was using this statement to write to the file:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(Program.file))
{
    sr.Write(string.Format("texthere");
}
```

But it stopped working when I switched over to simply using:

```
File.AppendAllText(Program.file, string.Format("texthere");
```

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: This is going to sound obvious, but you don't have your log file open in another program while you're trying to write to it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I see a

```
 File.Create(Program.file);
```

which is unnecessary and probably the direct problem here.

It does not just create an empty file but it also opens and returns a FileStream object that you do not close anywhere. The opened FileStream is not shareable so it causes AppendAllText() to fail.

Just remove that line, `AppendAllText()` includes the logic to [create the file if it does not already exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)